# How can I reduce table size in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have a database named "**bongoTv**" where lots of table but I found one table its size about **20GB** with less amount of data.

**After removing few row storage did not reduced. Then I ran a command
OPTIMIZE TABLE notifiation  to re-indexing. But It increase its size to 25GB.**

As per my undersetting with other DBMS it should be reduce its size but why its size increased, I think it cached previous information somewhere.

After searching on web I found need to configure with **innodb_file_per_table=ON**. But here in my configuration it is also enabled. But it did not worked.

Need expert opinion who dedicatedly working on this MySQL.
In that case what need to do from my end, what is the solution this issue?

@Louis &
@P.Salmon  Can you help me on this?

Thanks in Advance who is going to help me on this.

Answer (score 4):

In general, InnoDB tablespace files never shrink. If you delete data, it makes some space "unused" and over time InnoDB will try to reuse unused space before  expanding the tablespace file further.

But there is also tablespace fragmentation. As you delete rows and leave small gaps of unused space, those small gaps may not be usable for new data. So over time, the gaps grow in number, and the tablespace uses more space than it should, if you were to store the same data as compactly as possible.

The free space that comprise full extents, or contiguous 1MB areas, are shown as `data_free` when you run `SHOW TABLE STATUS`. But smaller gaps of unused space are not shown. MySQL has no way of reporting the "crumbs" of unused space.

When you use OPTIMIZE TABLE on an InnoDB table, it still cannot shrink the tablespace, it only copies data to a new tablespace. It tries to defragment the data, leaving out the gaps where possible. So if there are a lot of large and small gaps in your old tablespace, the new tablespace should have a smaller total size.

However, while filling pages of the new tablespace, InnoDB deliberately leaves 1/16 of each page unused, to allow for future updates that might need just a little bit more room. So in theory, you might see OPTIMIZE TABLE cause the file to grow larger if the original was very compact and the new file was created with more "elbow room."

But that still does not account for the 20GB to 25GB change you saw. That might be because sizes are cached. That is, the old file was in fact 25GB, but the table status was not reporting it. MySQL 8.0 especially has some caching behavior on some table statistics: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=86170

### So how to reduce the table size in MySQL?

- **Deleting rows** is the most effective way. If you don't need data to be in the database anymore, delete it. If you might need data for archival purposes but don't need to query it every day, then copy it out to some long-term archiving format, or another database instance on a large-capacity server, and then delete the data from your primary database.
- **Changing data types** to be smaller. For example, why use a BIGINT (64-bits) when a SMALLINT (16-bits) is sufficient for the values you store? It may seem like a small change, but it adds up. Values are stored in the row, but also stored again in any indexes that include that column.
- **Using compression**. The best results are in text and strings that store readable text. The amount of compression depends on the nature of the data. Don't count on this too much, because at best one can expect a 2:1 ratio of compression, and often not even that much.

Ultimately, databases tend to grow larger, and often even the rate of growth accelerates. If you accumulate a lot of data and never delete or archive them, you must make a strategy to support the growth. You may just have to get larger and larger storage volumes.

Comment: Thanks for your nice explanation and also thanks for links, I think it will also help me to explore more. ** Now I am planning to backup that table table to somewhere in my disk and later truncate that large table . And finally import that backup file. I am not sure whether it is going to free up my space or not. Do you have any idea on it? or  did anything like this to free up  space?

Comment: `TRUNCATE TABLE` does reduce the tablespace size to zero. It really creates a new tablespace and then drops the old one. Whereas `DELETE` does not reduce the tablespace size, it only leaves some space within the file as free space.

Comment: I run OPTIMIZE TABLE command  everyday at 5 AM using  EVENT, where another event run 12 AM to 4AM to purge data from that large table to make it much lighter. But I am afraid because,  if somehow  it (OPTIMIZE TABLE ) fails to recreate that table again then what will happen? I am not sure whether it is a recommended method or not. Or should I run it manually ? @Bill Karwin since you expert on this you know better answer. Thanks again for sharing  your knowledge.

Comment: I don't run OPTIMIZE TABLE that often. Maybe once per year, and only if there is reason to think there is major fragmentation in the given table. I don't mind slight fragmentation, that's bound to happen over time. Just make sure you have a generously sized storage volume.

Comment: If OPTIMIZE TABLE fails for some reason (this is very rare), it should just abort and drop the copy table. The original table will still be there, and that will be the canonical copy. I have never experienced data corruption from OPTIMIZE TABLE.

Comment: For what it's worth, 25GB is not too large as a MySQL table. At my last job, I didn't worry about table size until it grew greater than 500GB.

Comment: omg 500GB for one table. That is huge. I did not ever seen table size like this.